# Define ansible ask_pass in playbook or at task level

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'm writing a playbook for specific servers which do not have key-based authentication configured, my ansible.cfg has:

```ini
[defaults]
ask_pass = false
```

As most of my servers are key based, writing a playbook in the same project directory using the same `ansible.cfg`, I can specify `remote_user` in the playbook but when I define

```yaml
ask_pass: true
```

it is giving me errors.

Here's my playbook & error. Note that I don't want to pass command line argument `--ask-pass` but I want it to configure `ask_pass` for specific playbooks

```yaml
---
- name: ping
  hosts: all
  remote_user: student
  ask_pass: true
  tasks:
    - name: pinging
      ping:
```

Getting this error:

```
$ ansible-navigator run ping.yml -m stdout
ERROR! 'ask_pass' is not a valid attribute for a Play

The error appears to be in '/home/student/playbook-manage/ping.yml': line 2, column 3, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:

---
- name: ping
  ^ here
```

If I run it passing `--ask-pass` from command line it works. I want to know if is this supported to be configured at playbook/task level. If yes what is the correct syntax?

```yaml
---
- name: ping
  hosts: all
  remote_user: student
  ask_pass: true
  tasks:
    - name: pinging
      ping:
```